# Weird behavior in javascript function

Tags: javascript, for-loop

This javascript should run the function `func` `len` times and then return whether it was successful all the times or not. Instead, the `for` loop is cancelled as soon as `func` returns false. How can this be explained? ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3srutg09/))

```
function do_something(func, len) {
    var res = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        res = res && func(i);
    }
    return res == true;
}

do_something(function(x) {
    console.log(x);
    return false;
}, 5);

do_something(function(x) {
    console.log(x);
    return true;
}, 5);
```

I would expect `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4`, but the output looks like this:

```
0
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Pedantic: You could just return `res` instead of returning `res == true`

Comment: That might return undefined in some cases and doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the first function returns `false`,  `res = res && func(0)` will assign `false` to `res`. The next time the line is executed, i.e. `res = res && func(1)`, `func(1)` won't be executed because `res` is (and stays) `false`.

`&&` is [**short-circuiting**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). Given `a && b`, if `a` evaluates to `false`, `b` won't be evaluated at all.